# Google Cloud SDK fails to install on Windows 10

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Having Python27 installed on a Windows 10 I'm failing to install Google's Cloud SDK.

Its install fails with:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Failed to install.
```

On its way to this failure it suggests:

```
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
C:\Users\c\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.
```

A working Python 2.7 is indeed in the desired place. Setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON doesn't fix its problem

Answer (score 1):

I removed the environment variable `PYTHONHOME` and the Google Cloud SDK installed successfully.